# Create dynamic variable in dockerfile by the docker image shell itself?

Tags: docker, shell, ubuntu, dockerfile

HTH can we make a dynamic variable and bake it into the docker image? **Using host machine shell is not an option.**

I want to have a linux system variable like this:

Docker file I tried:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

#tried both of these:
RUN echo "DYN_VAR=$(cat /etc/issue)-something" >> /etc/environment
# or 
RUN echo "export DYN_VAR=$(cat /etc/issue)-something" >> /etc/profile
```

I want the above docker image to have DYN_VAR setup as system variable so no matter with what shell I run the docker I can access that variable.

e.x.

```sh
> docker build . -t temp
> docker run --rm -it --entrypoint "" temp sh

# echo $DYN_VAR
```

> This is just a simplified example of my usecase.

Comment: My base image is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What part isn't working? Is it writing to those files but they aren't loading as expected? Or it looks like your `npm list -g` is executing at image build time when maybe you want it executing at run time when the shell is started? Are the resulting contents of /etc/environment what you want?

Comment: yes it writes to the files successfully , but when I run the docker `docker run ...` the variables are not exported.
but the files have been modified correctly.

Comment: You say the files are writing successfully, but if you want `npm list -g` to run when you run the image, that's not what's happening. What are your ENTRYPOINT and CMD? What is your full `docker run` command? My guess is you're not using a command that makes use of those files.

Comment: Agreed, it would help to know the ENTRYPOINT and/or CMD, as well as the full `docker run` command. Your commands may not be invoking the shell in a way that loads those files (dash/bash/sh/interactive/login/etc...)

Comment: These questions are irrelevant, I update the question with and exact simplified scenario